# How to upload file(image) in IE8 (javascript to webservice)- No use of FileReader APIs, no Apache webserver (no PHP)

Tags: javascript, web-services, internet-explorer-8, upload, filereader

How do I upload a file in **IE8 without the use of FileReader APIs and also no use of php**.

I've seen tons of answers suggesting to use iframe but i think it needs php file where I would post. I am only using html and javascript/jquery on my client side script and c# on my server side script.

Currently I have this on my site.htm:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="file" id="txtUploadFile" accept="image/*" onchange="changetext();" style="display:none"/>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <input type=submit id="submitButton" value="Submit" onclick="doUpload()"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Note: Maximum file size is 5MB.</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

and this on my webservice /UploadFile.asmx/SaveSRLogoPhoto method

```
public SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string filePath)
{
    DataSet ds = null;
    Hashtable param = new Hashtable();
    SRLogoPhoto srlp = new SRLogoPhoto();

    try
    {

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        Byte[] b = new Byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
        fs.Close();
        SqlParameter P = new SqlParameter("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary, b.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, b);

        string sqlStr = "UPDATE SRSiteLogo SET srImage = @Picture ";

        param.Add("Picture", P);

        ds = dbHelper.GetDataSet(sqlStr, param);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        srlp.Error = "SaveSRLogoPhotoSite() web method failed on call to dbHelper.GetDataSet - " + ex.Message;
    }

    return srlp;
}
```

I just want to pass a server filepath of the image file im trying to upload on my webservice. Can this be done on client side? If not, I can pass binary from my html file to webservice. But I dont know how that's possible in **IE8 and without the use of filereader apis and php**

**HELP PLS**. BEEN LOOKING FOR ANSWERS FOR A WEEK! :(

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen tons of answers suggesting to use iframe

Yes. That is the only sane way to do this for ancient browsers.

> but i think it needs php file where I would post.

It doesn't. It just needs the server to accept and process the HTTP request.

> I am only using html and javascript/jquery on my client side script and c# on my server side script.

You can use C# to accept HTTP POST requests with files in the submitted data.

Comment: Do you have an example of uploading using iframe and send request to c#? I've been searching but all I see were php codes which I cannot use..

Comment: There is no difference between sending a request to an end point handled by C# and one handled by PHP. The client doesn't know or care about the internals of the server.

Comment: Um. So for my situation above, instead of the path what will I pass to my webservice then? Is it possible to get path from iframe? or do I have to pass something else and modify my current method in my webservice. really sorry, newbie here..